# Why is MySQL using 4 bytes for each character when selecting something from a derived table when it has a concat() using a utf8mb4 charset?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, group-concat, derived-table

Starting from this table with a `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS preferences;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preferences
(
    id      int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int          not null,
    title   varchar(150) not null
) collate = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

using these values:

```
INSERT INTO preferences (user_id, title) VALUES (1, 'Preference 1'), (1, 'Preference 2'), (1, 'Preference 3'), (1, 'Preference 4'), (1, 'Preference 5');
```

This query

```
SELECT CONCAT('"', GROUP_CONCAT(p.title SEPARATOR '","'), '"') AS title
FROM preferences AS p
GROUP BY p.user_id
```

with a `group_concat_max_len=64` results in

| title |
| --- |
| "Preference 1","Preference 2","Preference 3","Preference 4","Pref" |

But when using that query in a derived table, like so:

```
SELECT preferences_grouped.title
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('"', GROUP_CONCAT(p.title SEPARATOR '","'), '"') AS title
    FROM preferences AS p
    GROUP BY p.user_id
) as preferences_grouped
```

you'll get only 16 chars (64/4)

| title |
| --- |
| "Preference 1","Pr |

This is not happening when the `concat` is removed or moved to the primary query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('"', preferences_grouped.title, '"')
FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.title SEPARATOR '","') AS title
    FROM preferences AS p
    GROUP BY p.user_id
) as preferences_grouped;
```

| CONCAT('"', preferences_grouped.title, '"') |
| --- |
| "Preference 1","Preference 2","Preference 3","Preference 4","Pref" |

So it seems that adding the concat in combination with a derived table ànd a `utf8mb4` charset causes the byte count for the chars in the result set to be quadrupled, meaning my `group_concat_max_len` should really be quadrupled too.

1. Why is that?
2. Can I do something using `COLLATE` to fix this / change this behavior?

Note: When the `preferences` table has a non-utf8mb4 charset, like the default `latin1_swedish_ci` collation, then there's also no byte-quadrupling going on.

Check the fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hQD6r3pE5pmgR3n2XA7VtX/5

Comment: Collations are used for ordering strings only. The character set influences how many bytes a character can take up.

Comment: Ok but collations are a particular version of a charset, right?
Anyhow, the question is mostly about why MySQL is acting (so strangly imo) like this, with the `concat(group_concat())` and derived table combination. Since the innerquery is giving a different result set when run separately.

Comment: No collations are not a version of character sets. Collations tell mysql how to order characters in relation to each other. A character set will have multiple different collations.

Comment: To me the question is the other way around: how come group_concat does not use 4 bytes / character for utf8mb4 characters in the first instance

Comment: >"_utf8mb4 uses a maximum of four bytes per character_"

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html#:~:text=utf8mb4%20uses%20a%20maximum%20of%20four%20bytes%20per%20character).

So, a simple 'a' would be one byte, but when using the combination in question, then suddenly _every_ char takes up 4 bytes :shrug:

Comment: That's the actual length, these buffers usually work with an assumption of max byte lengths per character. Same as max index length issues. I could not find anything useful in the mysql documentation. May be worthwhile to raise it as a bug on mysql's bug reporting website and see what they come back with. The behaviour definitely seems inconsistent.

Comment: Ok, I was hesitating to raise a bug ticket, and wanted to check with some other people first, but I'll guess I'll have to do that then, thanks!

Comment: Pls do share the response you get.

Comment: The [bug has been verified](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103279). Now we wait... :-)

Comment: Nice one! The categorisation is non-critical and v8 is unaffected, so probably not too high up on the bugfix priority list...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in MySQL 5.x, and it has been [reported](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103279) as such.